# Android: Find Push Notification Settings from App

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine from the android app if the user has disabled push notifications on the app through settings?

Comment: When you say "push notifications", do you mean "notifications" or "push messages", as they are not the same thing?

Comment: The "Show Notifications" check box in Settings. I am assuming that flag is to disable "Push Messages" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am assuming that flag is to disable "Push Messages" ?

No.

"Push" is a means of delivering information to a device, initiated by a server, rather than being initiated by a client. The most commonly used communications engine for Android that is thought of as "push" is Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

The "Show Notifications" checkbox in Settings controls whether the device should show `Notification` requests from this app (and, secondarily, whether the app can show a `Toast`).

While a `Notification` request *can* be created as the result of a GCM-style push, they are completely separate things. GCM does not *automatically* result in a `Notification`, and few `Notification` requests have anything to do with GCM.